# showing one user picture to another on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, image

I want to build an application that shows one user the pictures of another (with his permission of course).

What I wanted to ask is if one user gives me permissions to see his pictures, does it mean I can show them to other users or I can only access his own images while his token is alive / I need a permanant token...

My question is general, but for the sake of it - my server side language is php.

thanks, and I hope my question was clear,
Yanipan

Comment: you'll probably need a permanent token with the scope of offline_access; I don't know specifically about showing his pictures to others, but you'll probably need publish_stream and user_photos added to scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access friends photo any time you just need extra permission 'friends_photos' for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (because alot of users dont like to grant offline access to apps because it tells them that your app can access your data at any time) is that you could only prompt for user_photos extended permission and store links/names of the photos on your own database on your server.  But to truly be able to list all of a users Facebook photos at any time, you will need both user_photos + offline_access.